# Substring function in JSP does not respond in an alert function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, el

The following code does not show the alert of "abc" but there is no any error message? Any idea to solve it?

```
<%@ include file="includes.jsp"%>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
...
$("input[name=rnrInd]").change(
                            function() {
                                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                                    alert(${fn:substring("abcxyz", -1,3)});
                                    $("input[name=mnpCustName]").val("PREPAID SIM");
                                    $("input[name=mnpCustName]").attr("readonly", false);
                                    $("input[name=prepaidSimInd]").prop("checked", false) ;
                                } else {
                                    //$("input[name=prepaidSimInd]").prop("checked", false) ;
                                }
                            }).change();
```

Comment: Your code has to work: https://jsfiddle.net/0bgnpLuf/ AND https://prnt.sc/bt4N9G6IoGQ3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function instead.

```
alert("abcxyz".substring(0, 3));
```

The JS code is evaluated when JSP have already been rendered. The `alert()` function expects the argument of type string that could be printed in the dialog, but instead it is looking for variable `abc` which is not available in the code. If you still want to call JSP function on the server then a better approach is to add quotes to returned value.

```
alert('${fn:substring("abcxyz", -1,3)}');
```